# Change css class after given number of items inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change css `display` value of items inside div using jQuery.
What I need to do is, get number of items inside the div element. (Ex- li elements).

If number of `li` elements inside the div is more than 6, I need to set `display:none` css value to them, while first 6 `li` items remain `display:block`

How can I do that?

I can get number of li elements inside div by using this code,

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    var itemCount = 1;
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if ($('#my-div li').length > 6) {
            var k = $('#my-div li').length;
            alert("no of items =" + k);
        }
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$('#my-div li').not(":lt(6)").hide()` to show the first 6 `li` in your div.

**Demo**

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  var itemCount = 1;

  if (true) { // changed < to > for the example

    if ($('#my-div li').length > 6) {
      var k = $('#my-div li').length;
      alert("no of items =" + k);
      $('#my-div li').not(":lt(6)").hide()
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</div>
```

Comment: when I run this code snippet, I can see all 10 li items displayed

Comment: @Joey Fixed, it was because the `$(window).width()` was different from this view and in the editor

Answer (score 2):

Here you got a very easy way to show only the first 6 elements with [slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_slice.asp) method, check this:

```js
if($('#my-div > li').size() > 6){
    $('#my-div > li').slice(6).hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my-div">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the list and hide it if the index is more than N.
Index start at 0

```js
$('.container > li').each(function(i, e) {
  if (i >= 6) { $(this).hide() }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using jQuery selector [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```js
 $('#my-div li:gt(5)').hide(); //Index starts from 0 so 5 is 6
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my-div">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
 <li>Item 5</li>
 <li>Item 6</li>
 <li>Item 7</li>
 <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, what's :gt(5) mean? is it a function?

Comment: @Joey Updated my response above with the link. It's a jQuery selector for `greater than (index)`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li:gt(5)").hide(); 
//List elements with an index > 5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```